# Remove the window title color for XamRibbonWindow

Tags: wpf, window

I have a wpf window using [XamRibbonWindow](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Ribbon.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.XamRibbonWindow.html) class, from an old code base.

I don't know why its black color will cover the minimize, maximize, and close buttons. I am not sure if this is caused by XamRibbonWindow either.

Those buttons still works, just hidden behind the title color.

[image: minimize button]

[image]

Also, if I press maximize button twice, the black color will be gone.

[image]

Anyone has similar experience and knows how to fix it?

The mainwindow.xaml is like:

```
<igRibbon:XamRibbonWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Geomagic.Shared.UI.WPF.IFGuiService"
xmlns:igRibbon="http://infragistics.com/Ribbon"
>

<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringData x:Key="Theme" Ref="Theme"/>
</Window.Resources>

<igRibbon:RibbonWindowContentHost x:Name="_contentHost" Background="{DynamicResource ContentHostBackground}">

    <igRibbon:RibbonWindowContentHost.Ribbon>
        <igRibbon:XamRibbon/> 
    </igRibbon:RibbonWindowContentHost.Ribbon>

    <local:DockManagerWindow x:Name="_dockManager"/>

</igRibbon:RibbonWindowContentHost>
```

Comment: You may want to post some of the XAML and/or c# code.

Comment: After some research, I think that behavior is defined in igRibbon:XamRibbonWindow, which is from http://infragistics.com/Ribbon. Cannot do anything unless I can change the source codes...